# Simple Slow Query Not Using Indexes

Tags: mysql, index

I have a slow query running on a large forum. The EXPLAIN synopsis:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN 
SELECT 
    COUNT(post_thanks.id) as thanked, 
    post_thanks.postid, 
    post.title, 
    post.dateline 
FROM 
    post_thanks 
    INNER JOIN post ON post_thanks.postid = post.postid 
WHERE 
    post.threadid = 562942 
    AND post.parentid != 0 
GROUP BY post_thanks.postid 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(post_thanks.id) DESC, 
    dateline DESC LIMIT 5
;
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                   | key        | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post        | ref  | PRIMARY,idx_parentid,idx_ksours | idx_ksours | 4       | const             | 7826 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post_thanks | ref  | postid                          | postid     | 4       | forum.post.postid |    1 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The indexes on the table:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM post;
+-------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| post  |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | postid      | A         |    32547435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | ipaddress     |            1 | ipaddress   | A         |     6509487 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | userid        |            1 | userid      | A         |     1017107 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | userid        |            2 | dateline    | A         |    32547435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_dateline  |            1 | dateline    | A         |    32547435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_ipaddress |            1 | ipaddress   | A         |     6509487 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_parentid  |            1 | parentid    | A         |    16273717 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_ksours    |            1 | threadid    | A         |     1713022 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_ksours    |            2 | visible     | A         |     1713022 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_ksours    |            3 | dateline    | A         |    32547435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_ksours    |            4 | userid      | A         |    32547435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_ksours    |            5 | postid      | A         |    32547435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post  |          1 | idx_ksours    |            6 | attach      | A         |    32547435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I've been trying to figure out why it is not using the index from the post table.

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM post_thanks;
+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| post_thanks |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |     7177648 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post_thanks |          1 | postid     |            1 | postid      | A         |     7177648 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post_thanks |          1 | idx_userid |            1 | userid      | A         |      797516 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| post_thanks |          1 | idx_userid |            2 | date        | A         |     7177648 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone have ideas as to why it is not using the index(es), or how I can attack this problem to make the query faster? Even if I remove the parentid portion, it still does not use the idx_ksours index.

** Warning, I'm not a DBA*

Comment: Does an index on (threadid, parentid, postid, dateline) speed up your query?

Answer (score 1):

Your query actually *is* using the idx_ksours index.

It seems like a pretty sensible assumption that `Using index` in the `Extra` field means the query is using the index, and then when that isn't shown in `Extra` then the index isn't being used... but that's actually [not what that means](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html).

Indexes, as you likely know, contain copies of the indexed column(s) data, in sorted order, along with a copy of the primary key of the row so the row referenced by the index can be retrieved.

When all of the data the query needs to examine in  a table is available inside one index, the optimizer realizes that reading the actual row data is unnecessary -- everything needed is actually contained in the index, and will be read from the index -- eliminating the extra lookup to retrieve the associated row from the full table.  This is what `Using index` means.

On the other hand, if the optimizer will using an index to optimize the query, the name of that index is shown in `key` column of `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

```
+------------+
| key        |
+------------+
| idx_ksours |
| postid     |
+------------+
```

So, you're actually using idx_ksours.

That's the good news.  The bad news, of course, is that this index doesn't offer enough of an optimization for your entire query.

Note that the second column in `idx_ksours` is `visible`, which is not evaluated by anything in the join condition or where clause, which means none of the other columns in that index are not used for this query -- it's only helping you find rows WHERE post.threadid = 562942.

The comment from @dezso addresses this -- if you had an index with all-relevant columns, in a helpful order, that index would provide more benefit for the query.

Comment: Thanks for the info - this is helpful. I also thought that perhaps it is because I am using parentid, however if I eliminate that part of the WHERE clause from the query entirely, I would think that the idx_ksours index would hold all of the values it needs, but I still get a FILESORT. How would I create an index that would be used properly by this query?

Comment: I haven't tested but I suspect ORDER BY COUNT() makes a filesort inevitable (as would ORDER BY any function's return value).  An index can "have" all the values it needs but if it contains ANY values NOT referenced by the selection criteria (e.g. your 'visble' column) cannot be used to optimize the query.  Also see @dezso's suggested index construction.